# Ansible playbook list variable can't display the item when printing

Tags: ansible

topic related to ansible playbook, i have a strange problem when trying to append items like (string + variable) in a list it's working fine, but when i want to print the results of that list it shows me items so strings but without the value of the variable. will give you an example.

I have one general main playbook and then roles.
One of the roles contains this code :

```
- name: Set list of successful jobs
  set_fact:
    list_of_successful_jobs: "{{ list_of_successful_jobs + ['POP unix job successed, link {{tower_url}}/#/jobs/playbook/{{id_jobtemplate_job}}'] }}"
  when:  status_out_6.json.status == "successful"
```

another role contains same code :

```
- name: Set list of successful jobs
  set_fact:
    list_of_successful_jobs: "{{ list_of_successful_jobs + ['POL unix job successed, link {{tower_url}}/#/jobs/playbook/{{id_jobtemplate_job}}'] }}"
  when:  status_out_6.json.status == "successful"
```

and in the general main i have :

```
- name: Print the list of failed jobs
  debug:
    msg: "{{list_of_failed_jobs}}"
```

Then when i want to print values i got :

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "POP unix job failed, link https://ocp3.ansibletower.net/#/jobs/playbook//8743732", 
        "POL unix job failed, link {{tower_url}}/#/jobs/playbook/{{id_jobtemplate_job}}"
    ]
}
```

the id_jobtemplate_job is already defined and tested i don't know why only the first one is printed with the value and the second one is considered as a string. Need help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out what was the problem instead of writing :

```
- name: Set list of successful jobs
  set_fact:
    list_of_successful_jobs: "{{ list_of_successful_jobs + ['POL unix job successed, link {{tower_url}}/#/jobs/playbook/{{id_jobtemplate_job}}'] }}"
  when:  status_out_6.json.status == "successful"
```

You should use :

```
- name: Set list of successful jobs
  set_fact:
    list_of_successful_jobs: "{{ list_of_successful_jobs }} + ['POL unix job successed, link {{tower_url}}/#/jobs/playbook/{{id_jobtemplate_job}}']"
  when:  status_out_6.json.status == "successful"
```

The difference is that you need to put the fist list separately from the item :

```
Yourlist: "{{ Yourlist }} + ['YOUR String {{YourVariable}}']"
```